# PuTTY log to disk in real-time?

Tags: putty, logging, real-time

Is there a way to have PuTTY log a session to disk in real-time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I know to do is what is pictured below, setting "Flush log file frequently".  It may not be real time, but it is pretty close.

[image: Logging in PuTTY]

Comment: Thank you! http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-logflush says: "[The 'Flush log file frequently'] option allows you to control how frequently logged data is flushed to disc. By default, PuTTY will flush data as soon as it is displayed..." (the section is short and contains more information)

Comment: Be warned that the setting "Flush log file frequently" may cause loss of data if your terminal uses a high baud rate and your log file is written over the network. I use a UART with 115,2 kB and a log file on a network drive and about on third of the data went lost without warning from PuTTY v0.69.